# Put the cost of the shipping method between the subtotal and total of the order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shipping-method

I would like to put the cost of the shipping method between the subtotal and the total of the order in the same column as the checkout in woocommerce, right now I have it in different columns. I hope for your help.

Thank you ! Attached images.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCKPJ.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lZ9Z.png

Thank you ! Attached images.

I have tried in the theme configuration and in the woocommerce configuration, but I can't quite manage it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, it's well explained and expressed, I can't find any other way.  even with explanatory images.